# At the (place) or at a/an (place)?

Tags: grammar

I barely can't distinguish using article *the* or *a/an* on some senteces. Are they have same meaning? So it doesn't matter if i use one of them?

For example:

1. I eat at a restaurant.
2. She is in the university now.

I've seen some sentences like them and i still don't get it when i use "a/an" or "the".

Please explain to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‘The’ is used when what you’re referring to is obvious. If there’s a university across the road that everyone goes to, and the person you’re talking to knows it, you’d say ‘*the* university’. However, if you don’t want to name the university, or it isn’t obvious what you’re talking about, you would say: ‘she’s at a university’.

Likewise — if there’s only one restaurant in your town, you would say ‘I eat at the restaurant’, but if you don’t want to name it for some reason; maybe you don’t want the listener to know, or, somehow, you don’t know, you would say: ‘I eat at a restaurant’.

Hope that helps!